# How do we prove That $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\leq 1/4$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

How do we prove That $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\leq 1/4$?

I have tried in this way:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(A)\geq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\\\\
\mathbb{P}(B)\geq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\geq[\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)]^{2}
\end{align*}

But I am unable to prove the required result.

Comment: I thin we missed your point. Are you referring to the union or to the intersection of the two sets?

Comment: what is the meaning of $AB$?

Comment: Likely means intersection, I think Ross uses that terminology in his probability textbook

Comment: AB means A intersection B

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$, due to the monotonicity of the probability measure, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \min\{\mathbb{P}(A),\mathbb{P}(B)\}
\end{align*}

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\mathbb{P}(A)\leq\mathbb{P}(B)$. Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) \leq \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B^{c}) \leq \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(A^{c}) = \mathbb{P}(A)(1 - \mathbb{P}(A))
\end{align*}

where the last relation comes from the fact that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A) \leq \mathbb{P}(B) & \Longleftrightarrow 1 - \mathbb{P}(A) \geq 1 - \mathbb{P}(B) \Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{P}(A^{c}) \geq \mathbb{P}(B^{c})
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?